# Sending UIElements via DependencyProperty in wpf

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, uielement

I have a user control with a `DependencyProperty` that takes a `UIElement`. So far, so good, the problem is I cannot find the element's children.

I think the problem is my lack of knowledge, could anyone tell me what the problem is and a possible solution?

I have made a small test-program like this

Usercontrol codebehind:

```
public UIElement TestSendUiElement
{
   get { return (StackPanel)GetValue(TestSendUiElementProperty); }
   set { SetValue(TestSendUiElementProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TestSendUiElementProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("TestSendUiElement", typeof(StackPanel), typeof(Test), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TestSendUiElementPropertyChanged));

private static void TestSendUiElementPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount((UIElement)e.NewValue));
}
```

xaml using the usercontrol:

```
<my:Test >
 <my:Test.TestSendUiElement>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2">
   <TextBox Height="23" Width="50" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
   <TextBox Height="23" Width="125" />
  </StackPanel>
 </my:Test.TestSendUiElement>
</my:Test>
```

Output is 0 children. Shouldn't it be 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is no Initialized  so count the object on initialization

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInitialized(e);
   Console.WriteLine(VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount((UIElement)e.NewValue));
}
```

And you will get count 2

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because whatever you assign to the TestSendUiElement `DependencyProperty`, it won't be part of the `VisualTree`. So `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(...)` will not work.

As a direct replacement, `LogicalTreeHelper` should do the trick.

And if you know the type of the object or can , then it's even better to use exposed properties like `ItemsControl.Items`, `ContentControl.Content` and etc., with the exception of classes inheriting from `Panel` (they're LogicalChildren property is internal).

If you are lazy you could also do the following (untested code):

```
<my:Test.TestSendUiElement>
  <ItemsControl Margin="0,2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <TextBox Height="23" Width="50" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Width="125" />
    <ItemsControl>
</my:Test.TestSendUiElement>
```

Then you change the type of the DP property to `ItemsControl`, and now you can access the children via this.TestSendUIElement.Items. An `ItemsControl` is probably not as lightweight as a panel, but using the `LogicalTreeHelper` probably wouldn't be optimal either. Depends on the scenario.

Comment: LogicalTreeHelper seams to be the best way in my case. But when i tire this I only get this output: System.Windows.LogicalTreeHelper+EnumeratorWrapper.

So i don't get any children i kan loop through. Should I get children?